# How to resolve Visual Studio 2013 SSDT SQL71562 Warning?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I have imported database as a project into Visual Studio 2013 as part of Data Project. When I look at all my warnings I see `SQL71562` messages that correspond to `unresolved reference to object`. When I looked at those stored procedures that are causing warnings they reference tables in same database by `[DatabaseName].[dbo].[TableName]` instead of `[dbo].[TableName]`. is there way to resolve all those errors at once without having to remove `[DatabaseName]` from object name?

Comment: If you are sure that `[DatabaseName]` causing the error then you can do a simple `find/replace all`

Comment: But I need to keep it like that once I deploy to the server, because in some cases procedures are deployed to two different database but pull data from same one.

Comment: It always better to use a `use [dbname]` statement rather. If cross DB connection is there then create a reference for that DB as well.

Comment: I'm not sure who `use [dbname]` would be applicable in this case as procedure is already created, just in the select statement it uses fully qualified object name instead of `[schema].[objectname]`

Answer (score 4):

SSDT provides a set of pre-defined SQLCMD variables. One of these is $(DatabaseName), that provides the current database name.

So you can replace your [DatabaseName] with [$(DatabaseName)] and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

You could remove [DatabaseName]. completely if in most cases the used tables/objects reside in the same db because then it is not required to definde a db Name..

Or you could follow lucazav's correct suggestion and replace it with a variable.